# Cannot find module node_modules\chalk\source'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, npm-install, npm-start

I updated node, npm and expo-cli now I'm facing this issue every time i run "Npm start"

```
Cannot find module 'C:\Users\xyz\projects\abc\node_modules\chalk\source'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\xyz\projects\abc\node_modules\chalk\source'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:353:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:566:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xyz\projects\abc\node_modules\metro\src\index.js:110:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
```

Metro Bundler doesn't start. Anyone who's facing the same issue? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello,  I hit the same error but on a different development environment. You can try to globally search for 'chalk' and make sure it is in a .lock file.  In our project chalk was in the yarn.lock file. Properly standing up the project with yarn install fixed the error.  If 'chalk' is missing from a lock file you likely have a dependency error.

Answer (score 0):

rm -rf node_modules && npm install

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Did it multiple time, unfortunately, this doesn't help.

Comment: How could this be a solution?